# Image doesn't save from URL when using UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c

"img" is actually a string with an URL in it, but I actually use it also as the name of the file

```
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:img];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:img];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  

[imageData writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];
```

In my view controller I got this:

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.initialImg];
if(img == nil) NSLog(@"image is nil");
[self.image setImage:img];
```

"initialImg" is an NSString with the same url as in "img". I also changed "img" and "initialImg" with another string like test.png, but this doesn't work either.

It prints out "image is nil" and not sure why it is nil...

**EDIT:**

Now I got:

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:img];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 

    UIImage *uiImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiImage);
    NSString *documentsPath  = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; 
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

And in another view controller in the viewDidLoad function:

```
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"image.png"];
    if(img == nil) NSLog(@"image is nil");

   [self.image setImage:img];
```

It still shows me "image is nil" and I changed the urls but they are correct

Comment: In general you can not use URL as a filename (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6114531/792677), post an example filename you wanted to use so that we can see if that is the case.

Comment: As I said, I've tried and changed it with "test.png" but it still says that image is nil

Comment: If you did what you said ("changed "img" and "initialImg" with another string like test.png") the image was not downloaded as test.png is not likely a valid URL for image loading. Please clarify what you've done.

Comment: In viewDidLoad your doing wrong. You are written data into directory so read data first then convert into image for that you need the `filePath` not only the image name see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is enough for you...

```
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:img];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:img];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

[imageData writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];
```

**in viewDidLoad**
    // You need the **storePath** not the url

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:storePath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 0):

For  `initWithContentsOfFile:` you should give the entire file path. I think you are giving only file name.
**Try case**

```
NSString *initialImg= @"test.png";
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:initialImg ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
if(img == nil) NSLog(@"image is nil");
[self.image setImage:img];
```

Otherwise you can use

```
self.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]
```

But it cause performance issues

**Answer for your question**

```
//Write image data into document directory  

NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *documentsPath  = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file


 // Read from directory using same file path 
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
```

Comment: But I'm not using the mainBundle I think?

Comment: @iosdevnyc if you use [UIImage imageNamed:] it knows only the image name. So it will search the entire bundle for the image. It affects performance.

Comment: In your answer you didn't use an URL, and I get those images from URLs with NSData